# Implement Ajax for a PHP Function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to work implement ajax due to maximum site load which PHP causes. But I am not aware of where I am making a mistake here. it is an anchor tag, when it is clicked the status of the particular row should be changed to a string which is hard coded.

### PHP WAY

USERDETAIL.PHP

```
<a href="USERDETAIL.php?changeStatus=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class=" btn-custom btn btn-success" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure changing status?')">Next</a>
```

#### Then it triggers This (IGNORE SQL INJECTION)

```
  if(isset($_GET['changeStatus'])){
    $id = $_GET['changeStatus'];
    $user=$_SESSION['user'];
        $sql = "select * from productOrder where id = ".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $sql = "update productOrder set prodStatus = 'Ready', By='".$user."' where id=".$id;      
          if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            header("Location:USERDETAIL.php");
          }
        }
     }
```

According to this way, it works neat, but the userdetail.php would refresh anyways which is a lot time consuming. Then tried AJAX way is below.

```
<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-role="changeStatus" class="changeStatus btn-custom btn btn-success" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure changing status?')">Next</a>
```

and that hits to

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".changeStatus").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var status =  "Ready";
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
              url     : 'action.php',
              method  : 'POST',
              data    : {status : status , id : id},
              dataType: 'html',
              success : function(response){
                console.log(response);
              }
            });
          }); 
        });
```

#### and in the action.php it is (IGNORE SQL INJECTION AGAIN)

```
if(isset($POST['prodStatus'])){
    $status = $_POST['prodStatus'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "update productOrder set prodStatus= '$status' where id=".$id;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result){
        return 'Updated';
    }
}
```

The output is nothing happens. in the console it is just adding int values. I know I am making a mistake, or understood AJAX in a wrong way. it is just one button click and the string in SQL should be updated without an input text / modal. Please suggest what should be improved?

Also instead of having a seperate action php for these actions, can I do all these in userdetail.php itself with Ajax? is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have typo in `if(isset($POST['prodStatus']))`

Comment: You can consider using a class I will call PortalUtil and write all the functions in the class using your inputs as parameters in the function.  Create and Ajax.php file for each function which is then called in your $.ajax url

Comment: @B_CooperA typo is corrected, no change. empty print on console.

Comment: @TemidayoDtuzzyOmotayo can you provide an example. I am not so familiar with AJAX, but I have an idea of what you are saying. but isn't this something similar to what you say?

Comment: Yes it is, you are almost there, you just need to structure your code to accommodate multiple functions using some OOP concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As B_CooperA pointed out, `$POST` should be `$_POST`.

Also, in $.ajax script `data` object your property name is `status` and in action.php you are checking it by `prodStatus`.
Furthermore, you should check the errors PHP is throwing in your script by enabling error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

It's better to separate ajax calls from your view files. You can create a Class to handle all of your ajax calls (You should also consider authenticating your calls as per your use cases).